# Suitable data structure to gain advantage in performance for broad data in Julia

Tags: julia

I’ve come from python to Julia, seeking better performance. Then I fell in love with this beautiful language because of its flexibility before its speed. After a while, I’m transporting my significant projects from Python to Julia. But in some cases, there are gaps in how I can gain Julia’s best performance in tasks with comprehensive data (Say data with thousands of rows and a thousand columns). In most cases, there are talks about using the built-in Arrays of Julia with a relatively bad sense if you want to perform fast computations since their size isn’t inferable by the compiler and this can lead to bad performance in some cases. But Array-like structures are the only hope to perform scientific computations. Can I do those computations by using Tuples? No way. There can be at least (and optimistically) a phase of updating elements in the procedure that Tuples can’t settle since they are immutable. I know in Julia we have `StaticArrays.jl` that proposes immutable data structures that have known length (Since they are static, *I guess*) in the compile time, which leads to a speedup in runtime. But when I have data with 5000 rows and 1000 columns, creating a `SMatrix` wouldn’t be possible:

```
julia> rnd = SMatrix{5000, 1000, Float64}(rand(5000, 1000));

[process exited with code 3221225725 (0xc00000fd)]
```

So, I saw in some developers avoided using the `SMatrix` in the source codes, and instead, they do the trick by creating the vector of `SVector`s since this can be done (in contrast with the `SMatrix` approach) and it’s relatively fast:

```
julia> @benchmark [SVector{1000, Float64}(rand(1000)) for _∈1:5000]
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 100 samples with 1 evaluation.
 Range (min … max):  40.097 ms … 76.436 ms  ┊ GC (min … max):  0.00% … 30.38%
 Time  (median):     49.359 ms              ┊ GC (median):    19.95%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   50.296 ms ±  6.551 ms  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  17.96% ±  8.91%

  ▃            ▃██▆▆▄▁▃  ▃▁
  █▄▆▁▆▆▄▁▄▆▄▇▇████████▆▄██▆▁▄▁▆▄▁▁▄▄▁▁▆▁▁▁▁▁▄▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▇ ▄
  40.1 ms         Histogram: frequency by time        72.5 ms <

 Memory estimate: 76.90 MiB, allocs estimate: 5002.
```

But, you can’t perform a fast operation on it:

```
julia> rnd_sv1 = [SVector{1000, Float64}(rand(1000)) for _∈1:5000];

julia> rnd_sv2 = [SVector{1000, Float64}(rand(1000)) for _∈1:5000];

julia> function dot(sv1, sv2)
           result = Vector{SVector{1000, Float64}}(undef, 5000)
           for idx∈eachindex(sv1)
               result[idx]=SVector{1000, Float64}([sv1[idx][i]*sv2[idx][i] for i∈1:1000])
           end
       end;

julia> @benchmark dot($rnd_sv1, $rnd_sv2)
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 2 samples with 1 evaluation.
 Range (min … max):  3.211 s …   3.232 s  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.27% … 0.00%
 Time  (median):     3.221 s              ┊ GC (median):    0.13%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   3.221 s ± 14.793 ms  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  0.13% ± 0.19%

  █                                                       █
  █▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁█ ▁
  3.21 s         Histogram: frequency by time        3.23 s <

 Memory estimate: 76.90 MiB, allocs estimate: 5002.
```

While I can do it much faster using regular matrixes and the matrix multiplication concept:

```
julia> rnd_mat1 = rand(5000, 1000);

julia> rnd_mat2 = rand(1000, 5000);

julia> @benchmark $rnd_mat1 * $rnd_mat2
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 7 samples with 1 evaluation.
 Range (min … max):  706.033 ms … 857.549 ms  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.06% … 12.98%
 Time  (median):     770.682 ms               ┊ GC (median):    5.71%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   775.272 ms ±  61.905 ms  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  6.11% ±  6.41%

  █    █ █                  █             █              █    █
  █▁▁▁▁█▁█▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁█▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁█▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁█▁▁▁▁█ ▁
  706 ms           Histogram: frequency by time          858 ms <

 Memory estimate: 190.73 MiB, allocs estimate: 2.
```

I know, the result was expected because in the case of `SVector`s I couldn’t take advantage of matrix multiplication (However, this is not my fault :D).

Maybe you ask why I didn’t create `SMatrix`es with the same dimension as `rnd_mat1` and `rnd_mat2`. Because it’s not possible to create `SMatrixe`s with this size! So choosing the best data structure in similar cases is crucial and I want to know what is the best data structure in Julia for data with a massive number of rows and columns in the case of **performing scientific computations** (considering the real problems in the world even may reach to the millions number of rows and even maybe in higher dimensions). Writing Julia code is easy, but I find it hard to write an optimal Julia code that dramatically distinguishes it from other languages like Python. So I want to get help and information to learn how to ease this difficulty in the case of choosing the best data structure for performing scientific computation on data with massive size if it's possible.

Comment: `SArrays` have no advantage for more than 100-element containers. And the inner line of your loop should read as `result[idx] = sv1[idx] .* sv2[idx]` and this takes 19.41 ms to run as measured by `@btime` on my 10-year old machine. That said, properly written Julia code using powerful packages like `LoopVectorization.jl` and `Tullio.jl` reaches the performance of OpenBLAS; I personally measured it and I quote the words of Tullio.jl author: _On a good day this will match the speed of OpenBLAS for matrix multiplication._

Comment: Thanks, @AboAmmar. The expression you've proposed doesn't lead to a result of matrix multiplication at the end, does it? I'm a little bit confused. Does `Tullio` take advantage of `TensorCast.jl`? Another question, what to you define disadvantage if you can get the result in 19ms on a data structure that isn't best fitted on the amount of data? What would you suggest for that size of data?

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to say that Julia is fast, like really fast, especially when carefully written. I'll give some examples below to see how Julia code compares to some of the most optimized codes.

Here is matrix multiplication written in Julia code with the help of Julia packages. I used `Tullio.jl`, which is similar to `TensorCast.jl`, along with `LoopVectorization.jl`.

```
using Tullio, LoopVectorization

function matgen(n)
    tmp = 1 / n^2
    [tmp * (i-j) * (i+j-2) for i = 1:n, j = 1:n]
end

function matmul(a, b)
    # transpose for cache-friendliness
    aT = transpose(a)
    @tullio out[i,j] := aT[k,i] * b[k,j]
end

n = 1500
a = matgen(n)
b = matgen(n)
```

Now benchmark my code against OpenBLAS (a spoiler: Julia code matches OpenBLAS or even slightly outperforms it on average):

```
@benchmark matmul($a, $b)
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 91 samples with 1 evaluation.
 Range (min … max):  50.620 ms … 80.234 ms  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 15.08%
 Time  (median):     52.428 ms              ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   55.428 ms ±  5.976 ms  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  2.83% ±  5.58%

  ▆█▄
  ████▃▆▃▆▅▃▅▄▄▁▁▄▁▃▁▃▁▃▄▄▃▅▅▄▄▁▁▁▁▃▁▁▁▃▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▃▁▁▁▁▁▃ ▁
  50.6 ms         Histogram: frequency by time          77 ms <

 Memory estimate: 17.17 MiB, allocs estimate: 117.

@benchmark $a * $b
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 90 samples with 1 evaluation.
 Range (min … max):  40.158 ms … 75.403 ms  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 8.52%
 Time  (median):     55.752 ms              ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   55.890 ms ±  8.547 ms  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  2.50% ± 4.67%

  ▂           █  ▂   ▅▂   ▂        ▂▂▅   ▂        ▂ ▂
  █▅▁█▅▅▁▁▅▁▅█████▁████▁███▅▁██▅▅▅▅█████▅█▅▅▅▅▅▅█▅███▁█▁▁▁▁▁▅ ▁
  40.2 ms         Histogram: frequency by time        73.1 ms <

 Memory estimate: 17.17 MiB, allocs estimate: 2.
```

For totally random matrices, the results are even more prominent:

```
a = rand(1500, 1500)
b = rand(1500, 1500)
@benchmark matmul($a, $b)
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 94 samples with 1 evaluation.
 Range (min … max):  49.783 ms … 79.087 ms  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 14.77%
 Time  (median):     50.926 ms              ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   53.926 ms ±  6.676 ms  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  2.95% ±  5.54%

  ██▄
  ███▅▆▄▃▃▃▃▃▃▁▁▃▁▁▁▅▃▃▃▁▁▁▁▃▁▃▁▁▁▃▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▃▁▁▁▃▃▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▃ ▁
  49.8 ms         Histogram: frequency by time          79 ms <

 Memory estimate: 17.17 MiB, allocs estimate: 118.

@benchmark $a * $b
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 83 samples with 1 evaluation.
 Range (min … max):  39.850 ms … 76.194 ms  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 9.49%
 Time  (median):     62.015 ms              ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   60.859 ms ±  8.666 ms  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  2.11% ± 3.51%

  ▁                 ▁   ▁▃  ▁         ▁█ ▆ ▁   ▁  ▁▁
  █▄▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▇▁▄▁▇▁▄█▁▁▁██▁▇█▇▇▄▁▄▄▁▇▄██▁█▇█▇▇▄█▇▄██▇▄▄▇▁▁▇▇▄ ▁
  39.9 ms         Histogram: frequency by time        74.9 ms <

 Memory estimate: 17.17 MiB, allocs estimate: 2.
```

And here is another comparison with the king of performance, aka Intel Fortran, for matrix-dot like your example above.

```
function dot_sv(result, sv1, sv2)
    for j ∈ axes(sv1,2)
        for i ∈ axes(sv1,1)
            result[i,j] = sv1[i,j] * sv2[i,j]
        end
    end
end
rnd_sv1 = rand(5000,1000)  # [rand(1000) for _ ∈ 1:5000]
rnd_sv2 = rand(5000,1000)  # [rand(1000) for _ ∈ 1:5000]
result  = similar(rnd_sv1) # [Vector{Float64}(undef,1000) for _ ∈ 1:5000]

@btime dot_sv($result, $rnd_sv1, $rnd_sv2) # 7.987 ms (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
@btime $result .= $rnd_sv1 .* $rnd_sv2     # 7.990 ms (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
println(sum(result))
  1249368.5894
```

And this is the Fortran code:

```
program dot_svs
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: m = 5000, n = 1000
    real(8), allocatable :: rnd_sv1(:,:), rnd_sv2(:,:), res(:,:)
    integer :: t0, t1, count_max, count_rate

    allocate ( rnd_sv1(m,n), rnd_sv2(m,n), res(m,n) )
    call random_number(rnd_sv1)
    call random_number(rnd_sv2)

    call system_clock(t0, count_rate, count_max)
    call dot_sv(res, rnd_sv1, rnd_sv2) 
    call system_clock(t1)
    
    print *, 'Elapsed Time :', real(t1 - t0) / count_rate
    print *, sum(res)

    contains 
    subroutine dot_sv(res, sv1, sv2)
        real(8) :: res(:,:), sv1(:,:), sv2(:,:)
        integer :: i, j
        do j = 1, size(res,2)
            do i = 1, size(res,1)
                res(i,j) = sv1(i,j) * sv2(i,j)
            end do
        end do
    end
end program dot_svs

Elapsed Time :  1.1000000E-02
  1249866.98320309
```

For massive data that don't fit into memory, I imagine there are other methods like reading data from disk or downloading from the cloud. I personally don't have such workloads to do this, but since Julia is fast at moderate workloads, it should be capable to perform well in bigger ones. There are of course some corner cases/rough edges in Julia arrays, but in the future, I think these will greatly improve. I'm waiting for fixed-size arrays, automatic SArrays for small array literals, better views, etc.

Comment: Thanks for this great explanation. Using the `matgen()` you created a skew-symmetric matrix. Why? Why you didn't do `rand(1500, 1500)`?

Comment: It doesn't make a difference, it's even more prominent that the Julia code is superior on average (see edit). The original matrix was taken from a random benchmark I saw on the Internet, but the Julia code doesn't utilize any special properties of that matrix.